# PhoneGap - Issue adding local plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm developing my first PhoneGap plugin and am having issues getting it to work. I've created a directory in the plugins directory and have created one Java file (Android), plugin.xml and the JavaScript asset file.

I'm trying to run it using the following command:

```
 phonegap local plugin add plugins\com.test.phonegap.plugins.MyFirstPlugin
```

I get the following error message:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Projects\messenger\plugins\com.test.phonegap.plugins.MyFirstPlugin\plugin.xml']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Projects\\messenger\\plugins\\com.test.phonegap.plugins.MyFirstPlugin\\plugin.xml',
  syscall: 'open' }
   [error] ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Projects\messenger\plugins\com.test.phonegap.plugins.MyFirstPlugin\plugin.xml'
```

When I navigate to the file, I notice that the contents of the plugin's directory have been cleared (really annoying...) and replaced with a file .fetch.json.

I'm running this on Windows 7 using PhoneGap 3.4 and Node version 0.10.5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a plugin it is copied into the `\plugins\PLUGIN_NAME` directory. If there is already such a directory, it is deleted before adding the plugin. So if your plugin is inside the plugins folder it gets deleted first and therefore can't be added anymore.

Just place your plugin somewhere outside your Phonegap project directory and then

```
phonegap local plugin add PATH_TO_PLUGIN
```

should work.